# How to Make dusty effect on a surface?

Tags: materials, particles, effects

How to achieve dusty looking on a surface, making a particle system was my first opinion but then I changed my mind!

It would've cost too much and now I'm stuck.

Comment: Here's a possible way: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-add-dust/

Comment: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-add-dust/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this. Here's one way in cycles as your question didn't specify which engine you are using.

- Start by adding an *input>geometry* node using the *normal* output.
- Next, add a *Separate XYZ* node, you will be using the *Z output*.
- A *color ramp* will be next, this will control the mix between the
  dust layer and the rest of the material. Plug this and the preceding 2 nodes into the *Fac* of
  the mix shader as shown below.
- You can either use a diffuse shader colored as you want your dust, or
  use a suitable image for your dust, it will go in the bottom input of
  a *mix shader*.

Here is the node setup with an image texture, to use without, simply don't use it.
[image]

This is a suzanne with the above material:

[image]